# Скрытие Div при нажатии вне его на jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

Вопрос в том, что есть кнопка, при нажатии которой toggle Div. С помощью следующего кода включил скрытие Div при нажатии вне Div кнопкой мыши:

```
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if ($("#registrationDiv").has(e.target).length === 0){
    $("#registrationDiv").fadeOut()}});
```

Но при открытом Div при нажатие снова на кнопку, Div сначала исчезает, затем снова появляется (т.к. нажат был элемент document-а). Как сделать так, чтобы он не исчезал при нажатии на ту же кнопку, когда Div открыт?

Answer (score 0):

Путем просмотра wschool появилась идея использовать dequeue(), и вроде как сработало. Дописал:

```
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if ($("#registrationDiv").has(e.target).length === 0){
    $("#registrationDiv").fadeOut().dequeue()}});
```